# Link to user profiles on Suggested Edit Dashboard

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, moderator-tools

Currently the moderator's suggestion edit dashboard displays user gravatars for each editor, but does not provide their user name or a link to their profile.  This makes it difficult to know who a user is.

Please link the gravatar to the users profile, and possibly add the user name *somewhere*.

Answer (score 1):

This is completed, also the dashboard was heavily redesigned.